# Speed of light getting lower in densed medium

Tags: speed-of-light, refraction, faster-than-light

In densed medium speed of the light gets lower so in this kind of situation is there anything which can travel quicker than light?

Comment: I suspect that gravitational waves may well travel faster than some frequencies of light through solids. But I am not up at all on the appropriate equations.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUjt36SD3h8

Comment: Massive charges particles traveling faster than the speed of light in a medium exhibit an effect similar to a sonic boom but [electromagnetically](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation#:~:text=The%20Cherenkov%20radiation%20emitted%20in,as%20VERITAS%2C%20H.E.S.S.%2C%20MAGIC.). But it doesn't necessarily sound like that is what you are asking about.

Comment: See this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Light.

Light slows down because of how it interacts with atoms. Nothing fundamental has changed about the nature of space or light. Light is an oscillating electromagnetic field. When it hits an atom, it moves the electrons in it back and forth. The vibrating electrons have mass and do not respond instantly. They are a little behind the incoming field.

Vibrating electrons set up their own oscillating field. This is light that travels on to the next atom. This repeats. Because of these delays, it takes light a little longer to reach the other side than it would without electrons.

Light of one frequency may interact, but light of another frequency may not. For example radio waves go through walls that block visible light. Or through windows that slow visible light.

Comment: Don't forget gamma rays...they're going $c$.